# App Center - What is Device and OS of the user?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-app-center

Just installed AppCenter to my xamarin.forms app.

Tested throwing exceptions and it correctly logs as issues in the Diagnostics section of appcenter.ms dashboard. From here I am able to view the report to say what device & os the user is using...

Question being how can I get these details by logging a tracked event...So was able to say

```
 Analytics.TrackEvent("My custom event 1");
```

and this will appear in my AppCenter dashboard on the Analytics-> Events section

So I need to include a line or two of code in the track event that will send back device and os of the user....can anyone point me in the right direction to find this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could track your events with properties.

```
Analytics.TrackEvent("Video clicked", new Dictionary<string, string> {
   { "Device", "Pixel 10.0" },
   { "OS", "Android"}
});
```

**Update**:

You could get the device information by [Xamarin.Essentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/device-information?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=ios),then you could pass them in the above method.

Comment: Hi Leo thanks for the reply. Yes I am aware of this... but what I am unsure of is how do I pass the actual device name and OS system of each seperate user.. so for example ‘apple IPhone 8’ and ‘IOS 14’

Comment: @John You could look at the update above,use Xamarin.Essentials to get the device information.